# Service vs IntentService for database remote operations

Tags: java, android, database, service, intentservice

I'm writing a service app which performs operations on a sqlite database and some client apps that are privileged to do different operations via connecting to that app using AIDL interface and ServiceConnection/bindService
My concern is concurrency because these operations happen too frequently in order of 100 milliseconds.
I don't need communication of client applications with service right now but it might be handy in future.
What is best option to do this? Service, IntentService or a subclass of service with similar modification to Intentservice?

Comment: why `AIDL` and services? why not a custom `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Because transaction data is much less than 1MB.

Comment: so what? if you want to provide Cursor based data (like sqlite query/rawQuery) then use ContentProvider

Comment: Actually I'm hesitating about that. Does ContentProvider use a shared memory like AIDL/service? In addition to transaction data size, does ContentProvider have any advantage over service solution?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics, BTW i never heard that service uses any kind of shared memory, any link for that statement?

Comment: Using AIDL, it will be shared memory. My friend insists on using service but I can't find a good reason in above document not to. Should we except any crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ContentProvider for this kind of job. You are afraid of transaction data size, but all components communicate with others through *AIDL* under the hood, so ContentProvider has the same restriction with size of Parcelable that you can pass through *AIDL* to service. This size can be different on different API's

Comment: Can you give me an example of sharing database among different apps using contentprovider?

Comment: There are tons of information on in-net. You can try something like: http://android-delight.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-sharing-data-between-apps-using.html